# Simple MobX Observable not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a simple React class annotated with a MobX `@observer` annotation and a simple data structure (annotated with `@observable data = { .. }`.  An action updates this structure but does render.

Here is source code of the class: -

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {observer} from "mobx-react";
import {observable} from "mobx";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

@observer
@withRouter
class UpdateDetailsForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  @observable data = {
    error: ""
  };

  onClick () {
    this.data.error = "error has occurred";
    console.log("Something has happened!");   // testing purposes
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="red">[ {this.data.error} ]</div>
        <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onClick={this.onClick} />
      </div>      
    );
  }

}
```

However, when I click the button the console displays ...

```
Something has happened!
```

... which proves the state of `data` is mutated but the HTML doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out!  It was the order of the class annotations is important i.e.

```
@withRouter
@observer
class UpdateDetailsForm extends Component {

...
```

This works!

But when `@withRouter` is the closest annotation to `class UpdateDetailsForm` it fails.

Also found this in MobX docs - https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html

> `_@inject('store')` before `@observer` will cause MobX to not trigger_

So the same thing happens for the `@inject` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out your `mobx` version. Before `mobx` version 6, this will work. From version 6, you need an extra `makeObservable(this)` in the constructor.

[This](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html) is the official thread.

> MobX before version 6 did not require the makeObservable(this) call in the constructor, but because it makes the implementation of decorator simpler and more compatible, it now does. This instructs MobX to make the instances observable following the information in the decorators -- the decorators take the place of the second argument to makeObservable.