# MobX console.log() works but render() method doesn't update using React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, mobx-react, react-state

MobX updates the store emitted by `console.log()` but does not actually update `render()` method of `React.Component`. What am I missing in this example?

```js
@observer
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  @observable data = {
    error: ""
  };

  onClick() {
    this.data.error = "error has occurred";
    console.log(this.data.error) // testing purposes
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="red">[ {this.data.error} ]</div>
        <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onClick={this.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-rgb-cfteq?file=/src/App.tsx)

Credit: Original code from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062216/simple-mobx-observable-not-rendering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MobX v6, calling `makeObservable(this)` within the `constructor` method is required to make class decorators work.

See [these docs](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html) for more info.

See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-waterfall-hd24m?file=/src/App.tsx) for a working example.